# Worklight 6.1 unable to start application in the worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am wiring to build and deploy my project, but my application could not start. I keep got this error:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /wl_project [project wl_project]
Error creating bean with name 'identityAssociationCleanupTask' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/D:/mobile/wl/workspace/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: user lacks privilege or object not found: CLUSTER_SYNC {SELECT t0.HOSTVMID, t0.ID, t0.UPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.VERSION FROM CLUSTER_SYNC t0 WHERE t0.ID = ?} [code=-5501, state=42501]; nested exception is <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: user lacks privilege or object not found: CLUSTER_SYNC {SELECT t0.HOSTVMID, t0.ID, t0.UPDATETIMESTAMP, t0.VERSION FROM CLUSTER_SYNC t0 WHERE t0.ID = ?} [code=-5501, state=42501]
```

I include facebook SDK and wikitude sdk in my build path. JRE version is 1.7.
I tried many things, like remove all the jar library, change java version, create a new workspace, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Based on the SQL state code in this message, it appears that the database user being used with the Worklight application does not have the necessary privileges in the database to perform the operation it is attempting to perform.  What database are you using with your app on the Worklight server (e.g., DB2, MySQL, Oracle, Derby)?  Did you populate the DB using the database creation scripts provided, or with the Server Configuration Tool?

Answer (score 0):

User disappeared... answer was:

> Never mind. I got it working by delete the WorklightServerConfig
>   folder in the workspace and restart eclipse as documented here:
>   [Worklight 6.1 JPA errors in log: can not start application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792515/worklight-6-1-jpa-errors-in-log-can-not-start-application). It seems to solve this issue.
>   Thanks